# Is there a limit to how many zombies a Mouth can summon?

Tags: dead-nation

The latest special zombie I've come across while playing Dead Nation was the "Mouth" zombie. Seeing how I find their appearance amazingly disturbing, I tend to get rid of them right away, but on the odd occasion that they manage to stick around long enough to "howl", they can summon a large horde of relatively weak zombies.

I was wondering if there is a limit to the amount of zombies that they can call, or is it possible to simply keep a live Mouth around to grind your kill count and points?

I admit I don't have the nerve to simply try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not, they will continue to summon zombies until they are killed. I tested this out with a friend when we were playing through, since we were wondering the same thing, and we let it go for a good ten minutes before we decided to kill it and move on.